# Authenticating Google Drive for devices

Tags: google-oauth

I am developing an application to access Google APIs and I have working the Calendar and Google Cloud Print APIs using OAuth 2.0 for devices.

A few months ago on the Google forum I asked about the Drive API returning "invalid_scope" and they informed us that for devices they were limiting scopes and hoped to open more up shortly.

We asked then about when the other APIs (like Drive) may open up to devices as we have customer asking us to add this to our application.

Hoping someone from Google can answer this question.  Thanks!

Request:

```
POST /o/oauth2/device/code HTTP/1.0
Accept: text/html
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-length: 92

client_id=xxxxxx&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

Answer:

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_scope"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we will be opening the device flow back up for access to more scopes. We're still working on the details but are aiming to make this change later this quarter.

Comment: Thanks, Adam.  Will there be an announcement anywhere where we can watch to know when it opens up?

Comment: Adam, any word on this.  Still not "open".  I have customers wanting to integrate more Google Apps into their systems which are not browser based and require using OAuth 2.0 for devices.

Comment: Any news on this yet?   Thanks!