# OAuth 2.0 for Google Drive and Devices still not Available... when will it be (if at all)?

Tags: google-oauth

This was asked a year or more ago but it seems some scopes, specifically Drive, are still not available to devices (those that are not iOS, Android, or do not have a browser).

I have clients waiting on this ability to implement the use of Google Drive with devices and was wondering if there was a simple yes or no if this is every going to be opened up to devices.

The invalid_scope error is constantly returned for this.

Thanks for any and all assistance.

Comment: can you expand on what exactly you are looking to achieve? It's important that you understand that whereas (a) the authorisation must be done using a browser, (b) this is only done once and needn't be on the same device that will subsequently consume the API.

Comment: Yes, I am aware a browser will be needed for the verification.  The hardware this is running on doesn't have a browser.  My question is pretty simple... when will Google open up Drive for devices?

Comment: You've missed the point of my comment. The device doesn't need a browser because the auth can be done on a separate PC.

Comment: But in order for the device to work with the google APIs it has to be authorized and get the access token.  My question I believe is quite simple.  I have Google Apps working with Cloud Print, Contacts, Calendar and others.  I am hoping to use it with Drive as well.  But as of this date, Google has it turned off for devices and invalid_scope is returned.

Comment: you don't authorize the device. you authorize a user/scope/app combination which returns a refresh token. you can embed the refresh token on the device and use it to fetch access tokens as needed. alternatively you can store the refresh token on a server and create a simple server app which the device can call to generate and return an access token

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  I've done many applications using other Google Apps on this device.  The point is, Drive does not work (it's not allowed by Google) with the device request.   Others Google apps work just fine and are "turned on".  I want to know if or when Google will open Drive up like the other apps.

Comment: Ok, here's how it works as clear as I can describe it.  The user runs a command to authorize a Google API (Drive, Calendar, Contacts, etc).  They specify their user ID and the API they want to authorize.  My application then does a cURL type request to Google and gets information for that API, returning a URL for the user to go to and a code to enter to allow authorization.  After that, they return to the device and it retrieves the Access Token and interacts with the APIs.  In this case, the DRIVE api returns "invalid_scope".

Comment: See this thread for more info from Google acknowledging this issue: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091806/authenticating-google-drive-for-devices for info from google